# app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

hey I'm new to programming so I thought I would just make a simple c to f converter but it keeps crashing on the emulator before I open it can anyone see why? i know the codes probally all wrong but its the only way i could think of doing it

```
package com.jamie.convert;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConvertorActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textout1;
    EditText textIn1;
    Button convert;
    int x=Integer.parseInt(textIn1.getText().toString());
    double fahrenheit = 1.8*x;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convert);
        textIn1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        textout1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        convert.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener)this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.convert) {
            textout1.setText(""+fahrenheit);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: for anyone to begin to help you you'll have to dump a logcat of your crash output...

Comment: Your error may be in your layout file.

Comment: What does this question have to do with javascript?  Why the javascript tag?

Comment: Have you tried just doing some of the step by step tutorials in the Android Developer's website. This might be a better approach than jumping right into a temp. converter.

Comment: Even when you fix the crash, you've still got the wrong formula!    F= C x 1.8 +32

Comment: "crashing on the emulator before I open it" did you register your activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code instead of this you'll get the answer

```
TextView textout1;
EditText textIn1;
Button convert;
static int x;
//int x=Integer.parseInt(textIn1.getText().toString());
//double fahrenheit = 1.8*x;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textIn1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textout1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            x=Integer.parseInt(textIn1.getText().toString());
            double fahrenheit = 1.8*x;
            textout1.setText(""+fahrenheit);
        }
    });

}
```

This would heppened due to your int x would not be getting any value from the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

try to `String.valueOf(fahrenheit);`
instead of fahrenheit in your onClick

also move your

```
int x=Integer.parseInt(textIn1.getText().toString());
```

to the onclick methode

Answer (score 0):

```
int x=Integer.parseInt(textIn1.getText().toString());
```

The above line will be executed immediately the `Activity` is started. At this point, `textIn1` will be `null`.

Also this line shouldn't be there in this way...

```
double fahrenheit = 1.8*x;
```

Replace those lines with...

```
int x;
double fahrenheit;
```

...and then change the `onClick()` method to...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.convert) {
        x = Integer.parseInt(textIn1.getText().toString());
        fahrenheit = x * 1.8 + 32
        textout1.setText(String.valueOf(fahrenheit));
    }
}
```